# Fuzzy K-modes clustering how to find the cluster centers

Tags: approximation-algorithms, machine-learning, ai.artificial-intel, clustering, data-mining

I'm trying to understand [fuzzy k-modes][1] algorithm (look mainly at page 3) in order to implement it.
I'm stuck at the **calculation of cluster centers** they said as shown in the link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788417/fuzzy-k-modes-clustering-how-to-find-the-cluster-centers

**I need to know whether the following is true or false and please correct me**

In order to get the center of a cluster we need to:

1. for each category in a variable calculate the sum of membership value for all the point, that the category belongs to, to this cluster
2. the highest obtained value to be set as the category of the center

Comment: I searched a lot and not found any reference that help all i've read are written in the same way as this paper. It'll be great if I got a reference or an example about this algorithm

Comment: I am not sure if this is in the scope. You will have a better chance of getting an answer on MetaOptimize or Stats.SE.

Comment: Wl-i is the membership value of the point i to the cluster l. points will have this structure A(1000,001011,000000001) 1000 means the first variable of A has the first category on ... B(0110,100000,101010000). suppose we're working on the 1st cluster so and we knew that W1-A=0.7 and W1-B=0.6 So will we take for each category the membership of the whole point? and make the sum for each point and chose the highest???